# Java selenium get following sibling

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

In [this](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) page I want to access the Game Locations table :

```
 <h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Game_locations">Game locations</span></h3>
 <table class="roundy" style="margin:auto; border: 3px solid #A040A0; background: #78C850; padding:2px; width: 100%; max-width: 740px;">
```

I use this in order to reach the h3 tag and after get the following sibling element which is the table:

```
WebElement gameLocationsHeader= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'Game locations']"));
```

However , I don't know how to reach the following sibling element (table) , I've tried using :

```
gameLocationsHeader.findElement(By.xpath("./following-sibling:*"));
```

But its not working , any hint ?

Comment: There is a typo in your XPath. Try `./following-sibling::*`

Comment: I've tried this but its not working too

Comment: WebElement next = gameLocationsHeader.findElement(By.xpath("./following-sibling::*"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node matched by your XPath is `span`. This element is NOT a sibling of `table`. So you need to locate `h3` which is parent of `span` and sibling of `table`

Try below code-lines to get required result:

```
gameLocationsHeader= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[span='Game locations']"));
gameLocationsHeader.findElement(By.xpath("./following-sibling::table"));
```